# Sway is not setting WAYLAND_DISPLAY

Tags: wayland, void-linux, sway

It seems that Sway is not setting `WAYLAND_DISPLAY`, which is causing `wl-clipboard` to not work.

I start sway from `.zlogin` like this:

```
if [ "$(tty)" = "dev/tty1" ]; then
  exec dbus-run-session sway
fi
```

I don't know what else might be relevant. I'm using Void Linux with elogind.

Comment: Can you check the version `sway --version`

Comment: Check if the sway configuration `~/.config/sway/config` does not override the `WAYLAND_DISPLAY` variable.

Comment: Check if the `WAYLAND_DISPLAY` variable is set with `echo $WAYLAND_DISPLAY`, if it is not set, you can try setting it manually with `export WAYLAND_DISPLAY=wayland-0`. 
Then check if `wl-clipboard` works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

If Sway is not automatically setting the `WAYLAND_DISPLAY` environment variable, you can manually set it in your `.zlogin` file before starting Sway. Here's an updated example:

```bash
if [ "$(tty)" = "/dev/tty1" ]; then
  export WAYLAND_DISPLAY=wayland-0
  exec dbus-run-session sway
fi
```

In this example, we set the `WAYLAND_DISPLAY` variable to `wayland-0` before starting Sway using `dbus-run-session`. Make sure to adjust the `WAYLAND_DISPLAY` value according to your specific setup if needed.

After making the changes, save the `.zlogin` file and restart your system or log out and log back in. This should ensure that the `WAYLAND_DISPLAY` variable is set correctly before starting Sway, and it should allow `wl-clipboard` and other Wayland applications to function properly.

If the issue persists, you may also want to check if you have the necessary dependencies installed for `wl-clipboard` and ensure that `wl-clipboard` is compatible with your specific setup on Void Linux.